# Does/will Sublime Text or Tortoisesvn support project bookmarks?

Tags: javascript, php, svn, sublimetext, development-environment

I want to add notes (or bookmarks, better if can write a description to a bookmark) on learning an actively developed project, and when I open the project, I can find all my bookmarks thus jump to line quickly, just like what one will do on reading a book.

So to say the bookmarks should be saved with project, and support updating when project got updated, then if the line number of a function changed, it will find the new line number and take you there when hit the bookmark.

Comment: FYI: there's a policy of closing questions that ask for library/tool recommendations here on Stackoverflow (check [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: @user2314737 thanks for let me know, I will change the question